# Upgrading to ver 4.7.4

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I am upgrading from CiviCRM ver 4.7.3 on WordPress 4.4.2. I am very new to CiviCRM. What are the exact instructions to upgrade with these versions? Have looked at this: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+WordPress but it seems to be extremely complicated for a minor version upgrade?

I am hoping that the newer version will make my site faster and more responsive. It's crawling right now after having installed 4.7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already installed civicrm you should be looking at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+WordPress not the installation instructions.